# How to convert DocumentSnapshot to Map<String, dynamic>?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

**I have a `DocumentSnapshot` parameter, and I want to convert it to `Map`**.

How do I achieve that?

Note: In my case `doc.data()` returns an `Object?`.

[image]

Comment: data() returns a Map, see https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase/latest/firebase_firestore/DocumentSnapshot/data.html.

Comment: You are right. It's really weird. But in my case, it returns `Object?`. Do you know why?

Comment: `doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;` solved the issue. But why the `doc.data()` returns `Object?`